# Is it possible to download paid apps for free from the Google Play Store in an Android Studio emulator device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play, emulation

I found these paid apps on the Google Play Store on my Nexus 5X Nougat (API level 25) with an x86 system image emulator in Android Studio.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/plXHp.png]

My question is is there any way in order to bypass this system on an emulator and be able to download paid apps like the ones shown in the above picture from the Google Play Store for free in order to test how they look like and function on the emulator?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Wouldn't that be hacking?

Comment: I mean just to see how their looks and functionality compare to my personal applications.

Comment: No, I don't think so. Any Google Play emulator will have a Google Play Store not unlike the ones you find on real device - I discourage this kind of action anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** The Google Play Store you see on your AVD there is exactly like the one you will find on a real device. Thus there is no way to get a paid app on that emulator without a credit card (or some other payment method) on hand.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't and there is no interest to do it.
What if that was your app and you were a développer ? Can you be pleased with that action ?